# laravel auto hard delete

Tags: php, laravel

I have methods where i can `soft delete` my model, `restore` them and `hard delete` (wipe from database) theme,

So far everything is ok, what I want in additional to that is to hard delete after `30 days` passed from `soft delete` info, so in that way even if admin forget to hard delete models it will delete automatically after 30 days.

Here is my codes:

`soft delete`

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        $user->delete();
        Mail::to($user->email)->send(new adminsoftdeleteduser($user));
        return redirect()->route('users.index')->with('success', 'User successfully deleted.');
    }
```

`restore`

```
public function restore($id)
    {
        $user = User::onlyTrashed()->where('id', $id)->restore();
        // Mail::to($user->email)->send(new adminrestoreduser($user));
        return redirect()->route('users.index')->with('success', 'User successfully restored.');
    }
```

`hard delete`

```
public function forcedelete($id)
    {
        $user = User::where('id', $id)->forcedelete();
        Storage::delete($user->image);
        return redirect()->route('users.index')->with('success', 'User Permanently deleted.');
    }
```

#### Question

1. what should i add to my `hard delete` function in order to delete my
   model after 30 days of `deleted_at` column data?

## Update

I've tried schedule way and as i cannot use cron job to test it so i used `php artisan schedule:run` and here is the result I've got:

[image: screen1]

Comment: [This will help you](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling)

Comment: @SaadSuri i think it should have easier way like using `carbon` right?

Comment: Depends upon you how easy do you find it. but it will work on linux because cron works on linux

Comment: @SaadSuri well i don't have previous experience with laravel schedule so i can't say i found it easy, or how i can make query for my need in Kernel. can you help with `carbon` or at least guide me trough this schedule?

Comment: @SaadSuri i have another question related to this maybe you can help with that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50073620/sending-email-on-schedule-in-laravel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Task Scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling#scheduling-artisan-commands) to automatically run a command:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function () {
        $users = User::whereNotNull('deleted_at')->where(
            'deleted_at', '<=', now()->subDays(30)->toDateTimeString()
        )->get();

        $users->each->forceDelete();
    })->daily();
}
```

Comment: should i add new function?

Comment: should i add `use App\User` to kernel?

Comment: i don't need to put this code in if statement right? e.g. say if user `delete_at` isn't null then run this code?

Comment: ok, as last question, i am in local obviously and i found `* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` where should i add this in my local?

Comment: i get this error `λ crontab -e
'crontab' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: i'm using laragon on windows as local server

Comment: This should run daily, actually.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Laragon, but this might help: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/running-schedulerun-on-windows

Comment: Already I've made it daily, just need cron job to test if it works.

Comment: Updated my question please check it.

Comment: ok, here is what i did (1) i have made one user soft deleted so `deleted_at` is not null (2) changed subdays to 1 for test (3) run the command.  `result` was command ran without error but user didn't delete from database

Comment: `idea` what if we use `onlyTrashed()` except using if statement?

Comment: Aaaaand it's working :) with `onlyTrashed()` except `whereNotNull('deleted_at')`