# sending email on schedule in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code below where i delete users on schedule,

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(function () {
            $users = User::onlyTrashed()->where(
                'deleted_at', '<=', now()->subDays(1)->toDateTimeString()
            )->get();
            $users->each->forceDelete();
        })->everyMinute(); // this is for test later changes to Daily
    }
```

## what i want to do

is to send email and inform them that their account has been deleted right before i delete their account which is `$users->each->forceDelete();` so I added my setup email to my function like:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(function () {
            $users = User::onlyTrashed()->where(
                'deleted_at', '<=', now()->subDays(1)->toDateTimeString()
            )->get();
            $user = $users->each;
            Mail::to($user->email)->send(new UserAutoDeleted($user));
            $users->each->forceDelete();
        })->everyMinute(); // this is for test later changes to Daily
    }
```

and it keep gives me error such as:

```
 Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Mail\UserAutoDeleted::__construct() must be an instance of App\User, instance of Illuminate\Support\HigherOrderCollectionProxy given, called in C:\laragon\www\mynewsite\app\Console\Kernel.php on line 35

  at C:\laragon\www\mynewsite\app\Mail\UserAutoDeleted.php: 21
  17:      * Create a new message instance.
  18:      *
  19:      * @return void
  20:      */
  21:     public function __construct(User $user)
  22:     {
  23:         $this->user = $user;
  24:     }
  25:
  26:     /**

  Exception trace:

  1   App\Mail\UserAutoDeleted::__construct(Object(Illuminate\Support\HigherOrderCollectionProxy))
      C:\laragon\www\mynewsite\app\Console\Kernel.php : 35

  2   App\Console\Kernel::App\Console\{closure}()
      C:\laragon\www\mynewsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php : 29

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLVED

I put my mailing code to another loop function like:

```
$users->each(function($user) {
  Mail::to($user->email)->send(new UserAutoDeleted($user));
});
```

and it's working just fine now.